# How to upload images from its src using generic handler

Tags: jquery, asp.net, generics

I am using this code to upload images using generic handler

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#btnUpload').click(function () {
var fileUpload = $("#FileUpload1").get(0);
var files = fileUpload.files;
var test = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
test.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
}
$.ajax({
url: "UploadHandler.ashx",
type: "POST",
contentType: false,
processData: false,
data: test,
// dataType: "json",
success: function (result) {
alert(result);
},
error: function (err) {
alert(err.statusText);
}
});
});
})
</script>
```

This code works with file upload control but I want to upload image by sending image src to Generic Handler

Like this

```
var src = 'Images/shaiwal.png';
$.ajax({
url: "UploadHandler.ashx",
type: "POST",
contentType: false,
processData: false,
data: src,
// dataType: "json",
success: function (result) {
alert(result);
},
error: function (err) {
alert(err.statusText);
}
});
```

Please help guys

Comment: Source `Images/shaiwal.png` is already pointing to server relative path or what?

Comment: Yes it's pointing to server relative path, where "Images" is a folder in my project.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are meaning by uploading an image which is already on server?! If you want to duplicate image on other folder or what?

Comment: Actually I want to download image using generic handler lets say 
src = 'http://.......Shaiwal.png'

Answer (score 0):

In your code check this line:

```
test.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
```

instead of using `files[i].name` as first argument, just send any other string you want, for example the src.

```
test.append(src, files[i]);
```

Then in Generic Handler you can create a collection of Keys which is the first argument you used in text.append:

```
NameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection Keys = context.Request.Files.Keys;
```

then you can easily access to any posted file's key using index:

for `context.Request.Files[0]` we have `Keys[0]` in Keys collection which can be the src you have used in test.append